# Print actual P-value only if >0.001

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Consider the P-values from these two t-tests

```
set.seed(1)
x <- c(rnorm(50,1), rnorm(50, 2))
y <- (c(rep("a", 50), rep("b", 50)))

t.test(x ~ y)$p.value

[1] 1.776808e-07

set.seed(2)
x <- c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50))
y <- (c(rep("a", 50), rep("b", 50)))

t.test(x ~ y)$p.value

[1] 0.3922354
```

The first P value is <0.001 and the second is >0.001. If the P value happens to be <0.001, can I get R to print out the P value as <0.001. If the P value happens to be >0.001, can I get R to print out the actual P value? So the result of the first t-test should be printed as `"<0.001"` and the result of the second t-test should be printed as `0.3922354`.

I am using `knitr` to convert R code to latex for my thesis. My rule is only P value >0.001 should be printed as actual P values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an if statement:

```
p_val <- t.test(x,y)$p.value;
if(p_val>=0.001) {
  print(p_val)
} else {
  print("<0.001")
}
```

Comment: Martin Dinov: that doesn't achieve what I need. I still need P value to be printed if <0.001, but I need it printed as "<0.001".

Comment: Ok, so just add the else case. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks should have thought of an ifelse type statement. Think this might be more compact within a latex document: `P <- t.test(x ~ y)$p.value; ifelse(P > 0.001, P, "<0.001")`

Comment: @luciano, unless P is a greater than 1 length vector, there is nothing wrong with `if(P > 0.001) P else "<0.001"`, and one could argue it is safer as it will throw a warning if the vector is unexpectedly longer than one.